# CUML fit functions throwing cp.full TypeError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, rapids

I've been trying to run RAPIDS on Google Colab pro, and have successfully installed the cuml and cudf packages, however I am unable to run even the example scripts.

### TLDR;

Anytime I try to run the fit function for cuml on Google Colab I get the following error. I get this when using the demo examples both for installation and then for cuml. This happens for a range of cuml examples (I first hit this trying to run UMAP).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c06fc2c31ca3> in <module>()
     13 knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
     14 
---> 15 knn.predict(X_test)

5 frames
cuml/neighbors/kneighbors_regressor.pyx in cuml.neighbors.kneighbors_regressor.KNeighborsRegressor.predict()

cuml/neighbors/nearest_neighbors.pyx in cuml.neighbors.nearest_neighbors.NearestNeighbors.kneighbors()

cuml/neighbors/nearest_neighbors.pyx in cuml.neighbors.nearest_neighbors.NearestNeighbors._kneighbors()

cuml/neighbors/nearest_neighbors.pyx in cuml.neighbors.nearest_neighbors.NearestNeighbors._kneighbors_dense()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cuml/common/array.py in full(cls, shape, value, dtype, order)
    326         """
    327 
--> 328         return CumlArray(cp.full(shape, value, dtype, order))
    329 
    330     @classmethod

TypeError: full() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

### Steps taken on Google Colab Pro (to reproduce error)

Here's an example, I install the relevant packages using this example from Rapids (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rY7Ln6rEE1pOlfSHCYOVaqt8OvDO35J0#forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true):

```
# Install RAPIDS
!git clone https://github.com/rapidsai/rapidsai-csp-utils.git
!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh stable

import sys, os, shutil

sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_NVVM'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/lib64/libnvvm.so'
os.environ['NUMBAPRO_LIBDEVICE'] = '/usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice/'
os.environ["CONDA_PREFIX"] = "/usr/local"
for so in ['cudf', 'rmm', 'nccl', 'cuml', 'cugraph', 'xgboost', 'cuspatial']:
  fn = 'lib'+so+'.so'
  source_fn = '/usr/local/lib/'+fn
  dest_fn = '/usr/lib/'+fn
  if os.path.exists(source_fn):
    print(f'Copying {source_fn} to {dest_fn}')
    shutil.copyfile(source_fn, dest_fn)
# fix for BlazingSQL import issue
# ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../../libblazingsql-engine.so)
if not os.path.exists('/usr/lib64'):
    os.makedirs('/usr/lib64')
for so_file in os.listdir('/usr/local/lib'):
  if 'libstdc' in so_file:
    shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib64/'+so_file)
    shutil.copyfile('/usr/local/lib/'+so_file, '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'+so_file)
```

Then I try and run the example below from cuML (https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#k-means-clustering)

```
from cuml.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=5,
                  n_features=10)

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=10)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.80)

knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

knn.predict(X_test)
```

This will result in the error at the start of the question.

Comment: This may be useful: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/issues/3670

Comment: Looking into this.  Seems that Colab is not importing the newly installed 8.6.0 version of cupy, but instead the older version of 7.4.8.  I have a fix, but it introduces a follow up issue.  Dx-ing right now.  Please stay tuned!

Comment: Thank you- much appreciated

Comment: Glen, if you can, please use 0.18 in Colab instead, for now.  that should work for you while we sort out this issue.  

!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh 0.18

Comment: Just tried this, using the script above replacing

```!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh stable```
with 
```!bash rapidsai-csp-utils/colab/rapids-colab.sh 0.18```

This resulted in the same error, now testing with 0.19- perhaps there are issues with the rest of the installation script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab retains `cupy==7.4.0` despite conda installing `cupy==8.6.0` during the RAPIDS install.  It is a custom install.  I just had success pip installing `cupy-cuda110==8.6.0` BEFORE installing RAPIDS, with

`!pip install cupy-cuda110==8.6.0`:

I'll be updating the script soon so that you won't have to do it manually, but want to test a few more things out. Thanks again for letting us know!

EDIT: script updated.